# CSS layout with header, footer and multiple 100% min-height content columns

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Expected result]

- Footer should stay at the bottom of the screen even if the content doesn't fill the viewport vertically.
- Content columns have a border that should always be 100% content height. As the number and width of columns will change from page to page, background-image to fake column borders can’t be used.
- There should be no scrollbars when all content is visible (Example 1).
- Solution should be all HTML/CSS, no JS.
- Minimum browser support should be IE9+ and latest desktop versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera; with no quirks mode.
- Width of the header/footer/content is always fixed (so header and footer don’t need to be placed inside content area). Height of header and footer is also fixed.

I’ve tried techniques from [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) and [this sticky footer example](https://web.archive.org/web/20161118224005/http://ryanfait.com:80/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) but haven’t been able to satisfy all the requirements at the same time. Any tips are appreciated.

Edit: So far the farthest I’ve got is by imitating tables which works correctly in webkit browsers but not in IE9 and Opera. [See the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xLTJp/).

HTML:

```
<div class="table outer">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="cell">header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="table inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">content 1</div>
                    <div class="cell">content 2</div>
                    <div class="cell">content 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer">
        <div class="cell">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table.outer {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.header, .footer {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.content {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.table.inner {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table.inner .cell {
    width: 33%;
    border-right: 1px dashed #c00;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not a semantically desirable solution, the only way I could find to achieve all stated requirements is to go back to the 90s and use tables for layout.

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wGtcF/).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="outer">
        <tr>
            <td class="header" colspan="3">header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
            <td>content1</td>
            <td>content2</td>
            <td>content3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="footer" colspan="3">footer</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; margin: 0;
}
.outer {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header, .footer {
    height: 25px; background-color: #999;
}
.content td {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-right: 1px dashed #c00;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Comment: With this technique, when the content exceeds viewport height, the footer stays on the bottom of screen and is not pushed down (behaviour illustrated in Example 2 is what is needed)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I figured out a solution that uses jQuery (instead of tables).

http://benpearson.com.au/web-development/3-column-fluid-layout-with-header-sticky-footer-and-100-percent-height-columns/

Comment: A site shouldn't rely on scripts for layout ... but I can't believe there is no other way.