# Fluid 3 column layout with header, sticky footer and full height columns

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, sticky-footer

I've been trying to create a layout with the following features:

- 3 fluid columns
- Columns that are full height
- A header
- Sticky footer

I found a similar question here: [CSS layout with header, footer and multiple 100% min-height content columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191306/css-layout-with-header-footer-and-multiple-100-min-height-content-columns)

The author solved the problem using a table based layout. I would like to avoid using tables if possible so I can easily hide the outer columns on smaller screens.

Here is the code I have created so far: http://cdpn.io/DqGfp

As you can see in my codepen demo I am almost there. A refresh produces the correct layout in all cases but ideally this should happen on resizing too.

Here are the resizing bugs I'm trying to fix:

1. Going from a tall window to a short window causes an unnecessary scrollbar.
2. Going from a wide window to a thin window causes the content in the middle column to go under the footer.

I've tried using

```
$(window).height()
```

instead of

```
$(document).height()
```

but that causes a whole bunch of new bugs.

Any help is VERY MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. I needed clear all the forced column heights before recalculating them when the window is resized.

Here's a link to a post about my solution: http://benpearson.com.au/web-development/3-column-fluid-layout-with-header-sticky-footer-and-100-percent-height-columns/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        The header
    </header>
    <div class="column green">
        Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="column blue">
        Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="column yellow">
        Column 3
    </div>
    <footer>
        Sticky footer
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background-color: orange;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.column {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    min-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VkPZU/2/)

Comment: Hi @Mohammad. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this layout breaks once you add some lengthy content. See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkPZU/1/)

Comment: change .`column`'s `height` to `min-height` :) and voila :)

Comment: Thanks again @Mohammad. But I'm looking for a sticky footer too.

Comment: @BenPearson I made it a sticky footer but the problem that when we resize the window it just go up or down with it and then when we refresh the page we get it down again so to fix that we need jQuery let me make a simple solutiona dn give it to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with two ways,

Use re-size jQuery function to do stuff again while window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     ////Write your code here again
})
```

Or you can use css properties to have fix positioned DIV at bottom.

```
position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; height:100px;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Maulik Suchak. I'm already using $(window).resize and a CSS sticky footer in my code. [See here](http://cdpn.io/DqGfp)